# Is the variable involved in a linguistic change from above necessarily a 'stereotype'?

Tags: sociolinguistics, variation

William Labov's (1971) concept of the 'stereotype' is that of a dialectal variable which has attracted sufficient attention to be the subject of overt comment or metapragmatic discussion. Such variables figure in the formality continuum.

The concept of a 'change from above' is a linguistic change that happens above the level of consciousness, i.e. speakers are aware that a change is occurring with this particular variable.

My question is, as both concepts require a variable/change to be highly conscious, does a change from above entail the changing variable to be a stereotype?

Comment: An interesting question, about regularizing terminology from different areas. It'd be interesting to know what Labov thinks about it.